# Google Login with GIDSignIn didn't have back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, google-plus, google-signin

I used the GPPSignIn to login google in the first time.

But it's rejected by App Store because it will open the Safari when login

So I replace the GPPSignIn with GIDSignIn.

And it works! It can login with WebView!

But the question is.... how should I back when I open the WebView!

[image]

Or say how should add the "Back Button" in this WebView

Thanks for your helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Try  html markup such as  My Button   into the content of your UIWebview using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method.

To capture the click event and prevent it from reloading content of your webview use this delegate:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
if(navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString: @"yourTag01"])
{
    //your action code goes here
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

For Action of your button You can use this :

```
if ([yourWebView canGoBack]) 
 {
  [yourWebView goBack];

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently had a similar problem. I solved it with import libraries  SafariServices.framework and run app again.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eonwU.png

Comment: same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813097/ios-google-signin-view-missing-navigation-bar-and-bottom-bar