# iOS Google SignIn view missing navigation bar and bottom bar

Tags: ios, google-signin

```
@interface GooglePlusManager() <GIDSignInDelegate,GIDSignInUIDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) GIDSignIn *gppSignIn;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController * localVC;
@end

@implementation TWNGooglePlusManager

(void)doGooglePlusLogin: (UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self setPropertiesToInitialState];

NSString* clientId = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"GoogleClientId"];
self.gppSignIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];

[self.gppSignIn setClientID:clientId];

if (self.gppSignIn)
{
    self.gppSignIn.scopes =  @[ @"profile", @"email" ];

    [self.gppSignIn setDelegate:self];
    self.localVC = viewController;
    [self.gppSignIn setUiDelegate:self];
    self.gppSignIn.allowsSignInWithWebView = YES;
    [self.gppSignIn signIn];

}
}

#pragma mark - GIDSignInUiDelegate
 (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController     *)viewController {

[self.localVC presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
@end
```

Basically, GIDSignIn is in my GooglePlusManager, and I passed current SignIN ViewController to GooglePlusManager, everything is working fine, except the Login page doesnt have backbutton/cancel button. I have tried setUiDelegate to self or VC, the result is same.
occurs in real 9.0 device and 9.1 simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out the answer is I missed SafariServices.framework. After I linked SafariServices.framework to the app, its working properly.